# How to make element displayed to true in Selenium using C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click an excel button on a page but i am getting "element not interactable" error.
When i debugged it, i see the element display is set to false.  However, i can go to the page and click element and it downloads the file so it works but not when i am running my code.  I have put longer wait time but that did not help either.
Here is my code

```
  var excelButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class,'exportLabel') and contains(text(),'XLS (1000 max)')]"));
       
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        excelButton.Click();
```

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and add the relevant HTML. My guess is that the element you are getting is not the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if user us able to click manually, then script should be also able to click it. I think, your page is rendering and during the rendering process the script is executing or browser has not completed its job and script executed.

just make sure you are selecting the right div and right element using xpath in case if you have two different div with same control tag and class.

let me know if i am of any help

Comment: i am getting syntax error on IWait wait.  the error says that i need to generate a class for IWait.

Comment: @moe yes, this is C# code. if you are getting error try alternative  driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60); sixty seconds wait initially to verify.

Comment: IWait interface is available in OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI library.

Comment: yes i have that library but it is not recognized.

Comment: now it is failing for"The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server.... click timed out after 60 seconds"

Comment: reduced to 50 sec and now it is failing for the same thing as before "element not interactable"  which means the element is displayed to false but at the same time i can go to the page and able to click it.

Comment: if you are not able to resolve IWait using OpenQA.Selenium,Support.UI try alternative driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225571/discussion-between-moe-and-aqdas).